# Shortest distance to surface normal line

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose I have a $C^1$ function $f$ which maps from $\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S$ be the surface in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ given by:

$$S=\{x\in\mathbb{R} | x=(x_1,...x_{N-1}, f(x_1,...x_{N-1})) \text{ for some }(x_1,...,x_{N-1}) \in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}\} $$

Define for a point $y\in\mathbb{R}^N$, the closest point on the surface $S$ as:

$$s_y = \inf_{s \in S} d(y, s) $$

Where $d$ is the euclidean distance.

I have been taught that the line from $y$ to $s_y$ is normal to $S$. I have found many proofs for this in $N=2$ dimensions online but cannot find the general proof for $N$ dimensions. How can I show this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the hypersurface $S$ you're working with is a graph is really quite irrelevant. In general, you can consider any level surface $S = \{x\in\Bbb R^N: F(x)=0\}$ with $\nabla F\ne 0$ on $S$; then when $x\in S$ is closest to $y$, the vector $x-y$ is parallel to $\nabla F(x)$ (which is the normal vector at $x$ to $S$). You can specialize to your case by taking $F(x) = x_N - f(x_1,\dots,x_{N-1})$.

One approach is with Lagrange multipliers. We minimize $\phi(x)=\|x-y\|^2$ subject to the constraint $F(x)=0$. Lagrange multipliers tells us that at a constrained extreme point we have
$$\nabla\phi(x) = 2(x-y) = \lambda \nabla g(x),$$
and so, indeed, $x-y$ is normal to the surface.

A self-contained argument (essentially proving the Lagrange multiplier criterion) follows from the chain rule, using $\phi$ as above. Suppose $x_0$ is the minimizing point and $g(t)$, $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, is any curve contained in $S$ with $g(0)=x_0$. Then two things are true: (1) $\Phi(t)=\phi(g(t))$ has a minimum at $t=0$; (2) $F(g(t))=0$ for all $t$. It follows that
$$\Phi'(0) = \nabla\phi(x_0)\cdot g'(0) = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \nabla F(x_0)\cdot g'(0) = 0.$$
Since the curve is arbitrary, it follows that all such possible $g'(0)$ give us the tangent plane of $S$ at $x_0$. In particular, since $\nabla F(x_0)\ne 0$, we know that
$$\nabla\phi(x_0) \cdot v = 0 \quad\text{for all $v$ orthogonal to $\nabla F(x_0)$}.$$
It follows that $\nabla\phi(x_0)$ is a scalar multiple of $\nabla F(x_0)$.  (We're using the famous property
that if $V\subset\Bbb R^N$ is a subspace, then $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$.)

Comment: I see - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in \mathbb R^n$ write $x = (\tilde x,x_n)$ with $\tilde x\in\mathbb R^{n-1}$.

Let $y\in\mathbb R^n$ and define the function $g:\mathbb R^{n-1} \to \mathbb R$ by :
$$\forall \tilde x\in\mathbb R^{n-1}, g(\tilde x) = (f(\tilde x)-y_n)^2 + \|\tilde x -\tilde y\|^2 = d((\tilde x,f(\tilde x)),y)^2$$

If $x = (\tilde x,f(\tilde x))$ is the point of $S$ closest to $y$, then $g$ has a global minimum at $\tilde x$. Since it is $\mathcal C^1$, we have :
$$0 = \frac12\nabla g(\tilde x) = (f(\tilde x) -y_n) \nabla f(\tilde x) + \tilde x -\tilde y $$

A normal vector to $S$ at $\tilde x$ is :
$$n = (-\nabla f(\tilde x),1) = \left( \frac{\tilde x -\tilde y}{f(\tilde x) -y_n},1\right)\propto x - y$$
i.e. the line going from $x$ to $y$ is normal to $S$.